# UML Domain Model some Jira business rules

Tags: uml, domain-model

I'm trying to represent some Jira the following business rules:

- A project has defined issue status and issues types.
- Same issue status and types can be defined across multiple projects.
- Each issue has a status and a issue type of the project it belongs to.
- Each issue is associated to a project, and a project has many issues.
- Only issues with status = "closed" and issueType = "task" have the customField1.

So far I have this representation for the 4 rules :

[image]

Would like some feedback on the representation and any sugestion on the last rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok so far. For the last bullet point you can add a constraint attached to `Issue` which reads

```
{ Only issues with status = "closed" and issueType = "task" have the customField1 }
```

and you should probably add the attribute `customField1` to `Issue`.

It's a bit strange, though, since attributes can normally not added dynamically. So probably it should be more like "can access" instead of "have".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Never used a constraint before but for what I found it is normally attached to a note, like in option A). Do you think any of the other options is correct? (options : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNjIB.png) Notice also added connection between field and project like in issueType.

Comment: Edit : http://www.agiledata.org/images/admInitialDomainModel.gif (http://www.agiledata.org/essays/agileDataModeling.html#InitialDomainModel) found this image. That gave me this idea (only looking at issueType) :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VheZZ.png. Don't know if by now i should make a new question but any feedback appreciatted.

Comment: Ambler's picture shows an association class and no constraint at all.